# Install latest GNOME version alongside Unity without deleting Unity's original package version

Tags: unity, gnome

How can I install `gnome-shell` without breaking anything from `unity`, in a way I don't break any of the packages, for example, keeping Unity's and Gnome's System Settings 'app' and keeping both Unity's and GNOME's `nautilus`?

Can I rename them in some way, for example `nautilus-unity`and `nautilus-gnome`, in a way the correct one administers the correct desktop, for desktop icons for example.

Comment: As far as I know, gnome-shell and unity are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Gnome desktop?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/577093/how-to-install-gnome-desktop)

Comment: @bodhi I've both, they live perfectly fine on my machine, do share some gsettings.

Answer (score 0):

## Install the minimal GNOME - shell + core apps:

Install `gnome-shell`, `gnome-applets` and `gnome-core` (may be installed already).

## Install full GNOME:

Install `gnome`.