# Gnome-shell can't install - broken packages

Tags: 14.04, apt, gnome, package-management, dependencies

I am trying to install `gnome-shell` but it shows me an error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gnome-shell

...

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome_shell : Depends: gnome-settings-daemon (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: gnome-control-center but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

[OP's original screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYyqo.png)

---

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

[image]

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

[image]

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

[image]

From comments:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f gnome-shell gnome-control-center gnome-settings-daemon
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-settings-daemon : Depends: gnome-settings-daemon-schemas (= 3.12.2-0ubuntu1~trusty3) but 3.8.6.1-0ubuntu11.2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Please post text files and program output listings as text, not as images (see [How do I save terminal output to a file?](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814)).

Comment: What's the output of `sudo apt-get install -f gnome-shell gnome-control-center gnome-settings-daemon`? Can you please [edit] your question and include it?

Comment: Please refer this http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121180/what-information-do-i-need-to-solve-an-apt-dependency-issue and add required output

Comment: the out put of sudo apt-get install -f gnome-shell gnome-control-center gnome-settings-daemon :
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-settings-daemon : Depends: gnome-settings-daemon-schemas (= 3.12.2-0ubuntu1~trusty3) but 3.8.6.1-0ubuntu11.2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Edited to include transcribe.

Comment: Oh dear, you have a bunch of other issues in your package management system that you need to or at least should fix before we deal with installing `gnome-shell`: [There is no public key available for the following key IDs 1397BC53640DB551](/q/766883/175814), [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](/q/65911/175814), [How can I accept the Microsoft EULA agreement for ttf-mscorefonts-installer?](/q/16225/175814)

Comment: Please [edit] your question, when you want to add information. Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](//paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Answer (score 0):

**Installation**

Please do the following. Open up a terminal and start with:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

followed by

```
sudo apt get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If you got errors continue with

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Finally finish with

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

**Login to Gnome**

*I am assuming you are using lightdm*

If that worked out, logout and choose 'Gnome' for the next login-session in the login-manager and login again.

[image]

Comment: :((. it doesn't work

Comment: @NhânHoàng: simply writing 'it doesnt work' doesn't help at all. Please tell us the output of each terminal command - otherwise its almost impossible to offer help.

Comment: The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-shell : Depends: gnome-settings-daemon (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: gnome-control-center but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Comment: Seems like you arent the first one with this problem - please check out this post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/577093/how-to-install-gnome-desktop

Answer (score -1):

Open up a terminal and run

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell gnome-control-center gnome-settings-daemon
```

Comment: it does not work

Comment: @NhânHoàng please give us more information. what do you mean by 'it does not work'? The command above is correct - so what happens if you enter it? Any error-output. Please add those informations to your initial post

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-settings-daemon : Depends: gnome-settings-daemon-schemas (= 3.12.2-0ubuntu1~trusty3) but 3.8.6.1-0ubuntu11.2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Please [edit] your question, when you want to add information. Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](//paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons.